# Concatenate index and string to new column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 3 columns(including index):

```
   name   age
 0 satya   24
 1 abc     26
 2 xyz     29
 3 def     32
```

so need to add one new column `detail` which will store the detail file name and the value in that column should be like `(str(file_index no))`

```
   name   age  detail
 0 satya   24  file_0
 1 abc     26  file_1
 2 xyz     29  file_2 
 3 def     32  file_3
```

to achieve that I tried the following

```
df['detail']= str('file_'+df.index)   #not working shows error
df['detail'] = str('file'+'_'+str(df.index))  #worked but not what i want
df['detail'] = str(s+'_'+df.index[0].astype(str))  #error
```

implemented for loop and iterrows

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df['detail'] = str('file'+'_'+row[index])   #IndexError: index out of bounds

for index, row in df.iterrows():
df['idx'] = str(s+'_'+df.index[row].astype(str))  ###IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

So please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) with `index`:

```
df['detail']= 'file_' + df.index.astype(str)
print df
    name  age  detail
0  satya   24  file_0
1    abc   26  file_1
2    xyz   29  file_2
3    def   32  file_3
```

Next solution is use `map`:

```
df['detail'] = 'file_' + df.index.map(str)

#python 3.6+ solution
df['detail'] = [f"file_{i}" for i in df.index]
```

Comparing:

```
#[40000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [153]: %timeit df['detail']= 'file_' + df.index.astype(str)
31.2 ms ± 423 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [154]: %timeit df['detail1'] = 'file_' + df.index.map(str)
16.9 ms ± 411 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [155]: %timeit df['detail'] = [f"file_{i}" for i in df.index]
2.95 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @jezrael-can u please say why this df['detail'] = str(s+'_'+df.index[0].astype(str))   did not worked

Comment: Because `df.index[0]` mean first item of index - it is `0`.

Comment: got that from df['detail'] = str(s+'_'+df.index[0].astype(str))  i had to remove  [0] after the index.it was always taking value at index[0]